# to get top 5 rankings from database

Tags: mysql, sql

In my table i have team and points column and I want to get top 5 teams .Teams with same points should be grouped and consider as one of the ranks so if 5 teams are having same points then all should come as one of the rank and next suceeding records according to team points

Comment: Ok, so what problem are you having? Have you examined the `ORDER BY` clause?

Comment: Show your query, til be easier to help

Answer (score 1):

TRY

```
SELECT DISTINCT(point), team
FROM tableTeam
ORDER BY points DESC LIMIT 5
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  SELECT team,
         points,
         (SELECT COUNT(*)
            FROM teams t2
           WHERE t2.points > t1.points) + 1 rank
    FROM teams t1
ORDER BY points DESC
   LIMIT 5
```

Comment: @diEcho: uhm... for the first team it will be rank 0, for the second - 1 otherwise ;-)

Answer (score 0):

There's no window functions in MySQL, so you'll want to extract the rank in your scripts.

Also, if I'm making sense of your ranking criteria, you're actually interested in getting the top 5 teams plus any additional teams that might have the same number of points as that in the 5th rank.

If so, your limit should be applied to a subquery on the point criteria:

```
select name, points
from teams
where points >= (
      select points
      from teams
      order by points desc
      limit 1 offset 4
      )
order by points desc, name
```

If not, a simple order by/limit will do:

```
select name, points
from teams
order by points desc, name
limit 5
```